# request.GetRequestStream() throws an “Value cannot be null” exception

Tags: c#, webrequest, .net-4.6.2

I have a function to do http request to a api servers who accept jsons:

```
 private static string DoRequest(object objToSend, string Url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            var jsonString= Obj2Json(objToSend);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("objToSend", "Objcet was converted to json string and produces an empty string");
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var sResponse = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return sResponse;
        }
```

When I run the line:

```
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
```

I got an Exception:
'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll ("Value cannot be null.")  System.ArgumentNullException.

in the StackTrace there was one line that says:

> "System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)"

**the Exception is disappearing by clicking the F10 key.**

Does anyone have any idea about, why the exception was thrown?

I want to emphasize that it throws the exception at the GetRequestStream(), that is before to any use of the stream.Write()

After wasting huge of time, I discovered that the excaption was thrown from ServicePointManager.cs that is part of system.dll.
Here is the function was causes the exception:

```
private static void LoadDisableStrongCryptoConfiguration()
{
    try
    {
        bool disableStrongCryptoInternal = false;
        int schUseStrongCryptoKeyValue = 0;

        if (LocalAppContextSwitches.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto)
        {
            //.Net 4.5.2 and below will default to false unless the registry key is specifically set to 1.
            schUseStrongCryptoKeyValue =
                RegistryConfiguration.GlobalConfigReadInt(strongCryptoValueName, 0);

            disableStrongCryptoInternal = schUseStrongCryptoKeyValue != 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // .Net 4.6 and above will default to true unless the registry key is specifically set to 0.
            schUseStrongCryptoKeyValue =
                RegistryConfiguration.GlobalConfigReadInt(strongCryptoValueName, 1);

            disableStrongCryptoInternal = schUseStrongCryptoKeyValue == 0;
        }

        if (disableStrongCryptoInternal)
        {
            // Revert the SecurityProtocol selection to the legacy combination.
            s_SecurityProtocolType = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        }
        else
        {
            s_SecurityProtocolType =
                SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            string appSetting = RegistryConfiguration.AppConfigReadString(secureProtocolAppSetting, null);

            SecurityProtocolType value;
            try
            {
                value = (SecurityProtocolType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SecurityProtocolType), appSetting);
                ValidateSecurityProtocol(value);
                s_SecurityProtocolType = value;
            }
            // Ignore all potential exceptions caused by Enum.Parse.
            catch (ArgumentNullException) { }
            catch (ArgumentException) { }
            catch (NotSupportedException) { }
            catch (OverflowException) { }
        }

        disableStrongCrypto = disableStrongCryptoInternal;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is ThreadAbortException || e is StackOverflowException || e is OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the full call Stack

> mscorlib.dll!System.Enum.TryParseEnum(System.Type enumType, string
>   value, bool ignoreCase, ref System.Enum.EnumResult parseResult)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Enum.Parse(System.Type enumType, string value,
>   bool ignoreCase)
>   **System.dll!System.Net.ServicePointManager.LoadDisableStrongCryptoConfiguration()**
>   System.dll!System.Net.ServicePointManager.EnsureConfigurationLoaded()
>   System.dll!System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.get()
>   System.dll!System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(System.Net.LazyAsyncResult
>   result) System.dll!System.Net.TlsStream.Write(byte[] buffer, int
>   offset, int size) System.dll!System.Net.PooledStream.Write(byte[]
>   buffer, int offset, int size)
>   System.dll!System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(bool async)
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetRequestSubmitDone(System.Net.ConnectStream
>   submitStream) System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteConnection(bool
>   async, System.Net.HttpWebRequest request)
>   System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(bool async,
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
>   System.dll!System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(bool
>   onSubmitThread, System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Net.TriState
>   needReConnect)
>   System.dll!System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>   request, bool forcedsubmit)
>   System.dll!System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>   request, string connName)
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(out
>   System.Net.TransportContext context)
>   System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>   RivhitApi.dll!RivhitApi.RivhitService.DoRequest(object objToSend,
>   string Url) Line 59

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Write` method will throw an `ArgumentNullException` when the buffer is null. In your case that would mean that `bJsonReq` is null.

Make sure it isn't null before you call `Write`.

Comment: 'bJsonReq' is not null.
by clicing the F10 key it works perfectly = it get the properly response from the server.
in addition - it throws the exception at the "GetRequestStream()" part, before it try to use the bJsonReq at all

Comment: Is it empty maybe?

Comment: @Developer is it being set by another thread, or by code running asynchronously? That could explain why it works in line-by-line debugging, but not when run normally.

Comment: @Nicholas Mertin internally, the sync GetRequestStream() method is using the async BeginGetRequestStream method. 
so it can couse an other thread to create the stream?
what can i do about?

Comment: @Developer never mind, looking at the code in your screenshot that can't be the issue. I was referring to the possibility of bJsonReq being assigned by another thread entirely, not from a return value as it currently is. Please post a stack trace of the exception, that will help in finding a solution.

Comment: to @Patrick Hofman. first i thank you for the reference. I edited the question so it contains the updated code.
I was added a new code to prove that the problem isn't being caused due to an real null object.

any help is welcomed.

Comment: Let me check the .NET source code tomorrow. Maybe there is something useful in there. You mean to say the error is ignored right? It executes as normal after that.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this microsoft document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3069494/cannot-connect-to-a-server-by-using-the-servicepointmanager-or-sslstream-apis-after-upgrade-to-the-.net-framework-4.6) adding this lines of code solves the problem.

```
private const string DisableCachingName = @"TestSwitch.LocalAppContext.DisableCaching";
private const string DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName = @"Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto";
AppContext.SetSwitch(DisableCachingName, true);
AppContext.SetSwitch(DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName, true);
```

there is in that document some more options to set this defination.

but the cons are probably the decreasing of security.
I'm looking for a smarter solution, maybe by setting the **ServicePointManager** somehow, In a manner that the **SecurityProtocolType** would not be null. For now I don't find such as.